# Have I made up this sentence correctly: "He never stays hungry."

Tags: phrase-request

> He never stays hungry.

I mean he always is going to find something to eat. He never bothers his stomach by leaving it to be empty.

Answer (score 3):

I find the sentence a little ambiguous as-is. You could change it to:

> He never stays hungry for long.

if you mean that he finds something to eat as soon as any signs of hunger start in his belly.

Answer (score 0):

> *He never stays hungry.*

This technically could mean what you want, but make sure the context reinforces it.

*Staying hungry* is a common expression meaning *being determined to succeed.*  As in: *The goalie for the Ottoman Empire's national team stays hungry by rewatching the video of the first time someone scored a goal on him.*

In total isolation, *he never stays hungry* could mean that he gives up on his goals before he accomplishes them.

If the context makes it clear that you are discussing literal hunger, then I would wonder if he doesn't stay hungry because he eats or because his body's response to lack of food is to stop noticing it.

A different suggestion:

> He always addresses his hunger.

This means to me that when he gets hungry, he eats.  He does not put off eating because he is busy, or because he is worried about eating too much.  When the stomach calls with a sincere request for food, he answers the call.

Answer (score 0):

"Stay" is a strong word, and implies a substantial period of time -- longer than you would normally expect someone to be hungry for. The sentence you've written could be applied to anyone who can find food on a regular basis. I would personally say it is too broad.

If you wanted to say that the person always has food in their stomach, you could say:

> He's/He is never hungry.

This expresses that there isn't any point in time where that person lets their stomach get empty; they've always eaten something recently.

You could also express it the way I have in this question; that is, "he always has food in his stomach." That is a bit longer though.